# What is the difference between DB2 sql codes -913 and -904 with an example?

Tags: db2

What is the difference between DB2 sql codes -913 and -904 with an example?

Answer (score 2):

An SQL code of -913 is UNSUCCESSFUL EXECUTION CAUSED BY DEADLOCK OR TIMEOUT. REASON CODE reason-code, TYPE OF RESOURCE resource-type, AND RESOURCE NAME resource-name

An SQL code of -904 is UNSUCCESSFUL EXECUTION CAUSED BY AN UNAVAILABLE RESOURCE. REASON reason-code, TYPE OF RESOURCE resource-type, AND RESOURCE NAME resource-name

A -913 is a deadlock, or two programs trying to get the same resource.  The classic example is program 1 updating table B, then A; and program 2 updating table A, then B.  Neither program can get to the second resource, so you have a deadlock.  To prevent this, all of your programs must modify DB2 tables in the same order (A, then B).

A -904 is an unavailable resource.  A dropped table or a locked table.

Both errors give you the name of the deadlocked resource or the unavailable resource.

Answer (score 0):

-913 is [SQL0913N Unsuccessful execution caused by deadlock or timeout](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00913n.html).

-904 is [SQL0904N Unsuccessful execution caused by an unavailable resource](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00904n.html).

-904 is specific to DB2 for MVS.